# How to sum over selected dates from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following query which generates customerid and days on which they bought a particular product, clearly each customer will have different dates on which he/she bought an item. What I want to do is get total purchase made on those days that the customer bought that product.

I have the ff query.

```
Select customerid, eventdate
into #days
from table1
where product='chocolate'
```

now i want to sum all purchases made on just those days customer bought 'chocolate'.
so i have

```
select customerid, sum(purchases) purchases
into #pur
from table1 a
where eventdate in (select eventdate from #days where customerid=a.customerid)
group by customerid
```

but the above is taking to long to run so i cancelled it.
please assist with a better query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking through carefully the following worked for me, and is faster.

--drop table #days
select customerid, eventdate 
into #days
from table1
with(nolock, index(ix_eventdate))
WHERE EVENTDATE between 20140401 and 20140430
and product='chocolate'

--drop table #pur
select customerid, eventdate, purchases
into #pur 
from table1
with(nolock, index(ix_eventdate))
where eventdate between 20140401 and 20140430

--drop table #first
select a.*, b.purchases
into #first from #days a
left join #pur b
on a.customerid=b.customerid
and a.EventDate =b.EventDate

--select * from #first

--drop table #purdays
select customerid, sum(purchases) revenue into #purdays from #first
group by customerid
order by customerid

select * from #purdays

Answer (score 0):

This gives sum of purchases for each customer **AND** for each of that day on which chocolate was purchased.

```
select customerid, eventdate ,sum(purchases) purchases
into #pur
from table1
where product='chocolate'
group by customerid,eventdate
```

If you want total purchase when chocolate was brought then do this

```
select customerid,sum(purchases) purchases
into #pur
from table1
where product='chocolate'
group by customerid
```

As per your clarification

```
select customerid, sum(purchases) purchases
into #pur
from table1 a
where eventdate in (select eventdate from table1 where product='chocolate')
group by customerid
```

I suggest you to apply indexing on eventdate column to improve query performance.

Comment: I think I have to let you know how the table structure is like.  table1 has the following structure,                                      customerid, eventdate, product,     purchases ...                                            1           20140101   chocoloate   10.00                                       1           20140203   candy        15.00      a where clause for product='chocolate' will sum just the purchase amt for chocolates, what I want is get the dates on which customer bought only chocolate, then sum all purchases including chocolate for those days

Comment: so first you want to find all the dates when chocolate was purchased and then group them among customerid and calculate sum ?

Comment: yes, calculate sum of purchases for all products including chocolates, on the days that only chocolates were bought.

Comment: check last query in my posted answer

Comment: thanks but that query means that the same eventdates will be used for each customer, in actual fact, each customer bought chocoloates on different dates, so for those different dates i want to sum(purchases) only for those dates that each customer bought the chocolates

Comment: After thinking through carefully the following worked for me, and is faster. (in different comments)

--drop table #days
select customerid, eventdate 
into #days
from table1
with(nolock, index(ix_eventdate))
WHERE EVENTDATE between 20140401 and 20140430
and product='chocolate'

--drop table #pur
select customerid, eventdate, purchases   
into #pur 
from table1
with(nolock, index(ix_eventdate))
where eventdate between 20140401 and 20140430

Comment: --drop table #first
select a.*, b.purchases
into #first from #days a
left join #pur b
on a.customerid=b.customerid
and a.EventDate =b.EventDate

--select * from #first

--drop table #purdays
select customerid, sum(purchases) revenue into #purdays from #first
group by customerid
order by customerid

select * from #purdays

Comment: post your comment it as answer so that it can be helpful in future

Answer (score 0):

The sum of all purchases by customer, counting only the dates on which he bought chocolate.

```
SELECT customerid, sum(purchases) purchases
FROM table1 a
WHERE eventdate IN
  (SELECT eventdate
   FROM table1
   WHERE product = 'chocolate'
   AND customerid = a.customerid)
GROUP BY customerid;
```

Comment: I think I have to let you know how the table structure is like.  table1 has the following structure,                                      customerid, product,     purchases ...                                            1           chocoloate   10.00

Answer (score 0):

Not very sure if this will work but try it out. If it doesnt then can you please provide sample data and expected output so that we can try it out in a better fashion

```
select customerid, sum(purchases) purchases
into #pur
from table1 a
inner join #days d 
ON d.customerid = a.customerid
AND d.eventdate = a.eventdate
group by customerid
```

OR try this query

```
select customerid, sum(purchases) purchases
into #pur
from table1 a
inner join #days d 
ON d.customerid = a.customerid
WHERE d.eventdate = a.eventdate
group by customerid
```

Hope this helps